# Calling SOAP service that receives DateTime parameter in format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", C#

Tags: c#, datetimeformatinfo

I am trying to call SOAP service that receives DateTime in format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss".
I managed to set format to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", but "T" between Date and Time is mandatory for call to SOAP service.

I tried with

```
int lcid = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID;
var formatInfo = new CultureInfo(lcid).DateTimeFormat;
            
formatInfo.DateSeparator = "-";
formatInfo.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
formatInfo.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
formatInfo.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
            
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lcid, true);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = formatInfo;

string sd = "2022-10-31T13:00:00";

DateTime sdConverted = DateTime.ParseExact(sd, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

result is DateTime in format "2022-10-01 13:00:00".

EDIT:
SOAP request creation

```
async Task<GetTimeResponse> GetTimeAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string username, string password)
{
   ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
   client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
   client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

   TimeRequest timeRequest = new TimeRequest
   {
      From = startDate,
      Until = endDate,                    
   };

   GetTimeRequest request = new GetTimeRequest(timeRequest);
   GetTimeResponse response = await client.GetTimeAsync(request);
   return response;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: "but DateTime that has that value" - a `DateTime` doesn't have a format at all. It's very unclear to me why you're changing the culture's `DateTimeFormat`. Please provide more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right. I should created CultureInfo like

`var formatInfo = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID).DateTimeFormat;`

Comment: @JonSkeet at first, format was `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, and with code above, i changed it to `yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt`

I hope this clears what am i trying to do.

Comment: Well, you changed the format in the current culture - you didn't change the format in the `DateTime` value, because there's no such thing. Again, we don't know what you're really trying to achieve. Something to do with SOAP by the sounds of it, but you haven't told us any more than that.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. You ran into an issue, thought of a solution and are now asking us to fix your solution. Instead you should ask help with the actual issue you encountered. So please tell us the underlying problem

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct about the `DateTime` value, 
I need to call SOAP service that only receives date in this format
`<web:From>2022-10-21T00:00:00</web:From>`

I have tried without 'T', and received error.

Comment: Right, so how are you creating the SOAP request? That's where you need to format the value, but you haven't told us *anything* about how you're creating the request, which makes it basically impossible to help you at the moment :(

Comment: (I suspect the problem is in your assertion that "I don't need string in that format" - it really sounds like you do.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you. I have updated the question with SOAP call

Comment: That really doesn't tell us very much - my *guess* is that you can add attributes to the properties to specify the format, but it would help if we didn't have to guess. (What is `ServiceClient` in this case? Your own class? Part of a framework?)

Answer (score 0):

Like said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0) the date time format you want is a standard type. It has format specifier `"s"`.

E.g.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
```

Will print something like

> 2022-10-31T21:33:06

Comment: I need to send DateTime in that format. To format string to be in some format is not a problem.

`sdConverted` should be in stated format, not it's string representation

Comment: @MilanMijailovic what are you talking about? An object of type `DateTime` doesn't have a "format". It's a data structure. It's internal handling of data is not relevant.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry. 
I have updated the question, as @Jon Skeet suggested.
I need to call SOAP that receives DateTime in that format, and that is the exual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answers.

@JonSkeet, @JHBonarius
Both of you are right, i needed to send string representation of DateTime.

Solution:
In Reference.cs file - created after importing SOAP service
I have changed data type of **From** and **Until** fields - from **DateTime** -> **string**.

After that i am able to call SOAP service with

```
TimeSeriesValueRequest timeSeriesRequest = new 
   TimeSeriesValueRequest
   {
    From = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
    Until = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
   }
```

Comment: Stack overflow is a community driven service to let developers help each other. Question and answers can and should therefore be useful to others. From the way both question and answer are written now, it's not clear what the problem was and how it was caused. And from the answer is not clear how to exactly fix it. Could you please rewrite both with all necessary details, so the QA can be of value to other developers?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated and i am hopping that problem and solution are better explained